# MobileFirst Game CheckCollisions

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

SA All

I am developing a game where elements fall randomly above a hero.

collisions are calcualted and works fine on MobileFirst similator, But Collisions doesn't work on real android device, Any Suggestions? if you need code snippets, which exactly should i share cause the App is too large to share

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should use a game engine/library, they have collision detection built-in.
For 2D, you have libgdx, cocos-2dx.
For 3D, libgdx again, Unreal engine, Unity 3D.

Comment: I have to produce it using MobileFirst platform -_-

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand that it was a game engine

Comment: Maybe checking source code of libgdx collisions methods could help you to write your own?

Comment: It's not a game engine, you're not wrong at all, we're just testing it's capabilities as a platform, I'll use libgdx and develop a native page for android devices, Thanks Louis